# A lower bound for the number of triangles that contain a particular edge

Tags: graph-theory

If $u \leftrightarrow v$ in a graph $G$, prove that $uv$ belongs to at least $d(u) + d(v) − n(G)$ triangles in $G$, where $n(G)=$ number of vertices in $G$.

In this question, I tried a lot. I know we are supposed to start with $2$ vertices and check the vertices they are adjacent to, but I'm unable to write the entire solution. Please help.

Comment: What is $n(G)$?

Comment: Number of vertices in G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in the direction you mentioned, let the set of vertices adj. to $u$ be $A$ and to $v$ be $B$. The set of vertices adjacent to both $u$ & $v$ $=A\cap B$. Note that
$$|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cup B|$$
$$|A|=d(u), |B|=d(v) \quad and \quad|A\cup B|\leq n(G)$$
Also, $|A\cap B|=$the no. of triangles asked since they'll formed with the vertices common to $u$ and $v$.
So, $$|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cup B|\geq d(u)+d(v)-n(G)$$

Comment: Thank you, it was a very clear solution. However, my question was recently edited to be "A lower bound for the number of triangles that contain a particular edge
". I'm just wondering, is there any upper bound to it to?

Comment: For that, we'll have to minimise $|A \cup B|$, which is the no. of vertices common to u or v, which is $d(u)+d(v)$, if I'm not wrong. You can get the corresponding upper bound then.